# Make a element ignore the effect of position absolute of an other element?

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with the positioning of the elements on my website. My website consist of a big div with `class="main"` and a footer. I want to put my main class with a margin-top of 80%. No mather what i put above this div, i want it to stay in that position. To do this i make it `position: absolute` and `top: 80%`. The problem is that by doing this my div ignore the document flow and my footer move to the top of the page. I can solve this by giving it a  `position: absolute` and `top:#` but I use the same stylesheet for other pages and then i will have to set a top for each of the sites. Is there any way to let my footer ignore the `position:absolute` of the main and stay right after the main?

Note: Sorry for my bad English.

#### CODE:

### HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
  <h4> Welcome!</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="FooterRotate"></div>
<footer>
     <div class="social"></div>
</footer>
```

### CSS

```
body{ 
    background-color:#3CC;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
/*    position: absolute;*/
}
/*Main*/
.main{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    background-image: url(../Media/backgrouds/Fondo.jpg);
    width: 120%;
/*    height: 1000px;*/
    top: 90%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;   
}


.content{
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 83.3%;
    margin-left: 24px;
}

#FooterRotate{
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    top: 1500px;
    left: -10px;
    height: 100px;
    width:  120%;
    background-color: #C70039;
    position: absolute;
/*    clear: both;*/
}

footer{
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #C70039;
    top: 1550px;
    left: -10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 110%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Give the body a unique class name for that page then you can apply a style just for that body.unique-class footer { /* styles just for this page */}

Comment: @vals I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make footer as a child element for .main div, then your footer follows the content inside main. So you can avoid using position: absolute to footer.

Changes in HTML: Moved #FooterRotate, footer inside .main div.

Changes in CSS: removed position absolute and its corresponding properties(top,left) for footer and #FooterRotate.

```css
body{ 
    background-color:#3CC;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
/*    position: absolute;*/
}
/*Main*/
.main{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    background-image: url(../Media/backgrouds/Fondo.jpg);
    width: 120%;
/*    height: 1000px;*/
    top: 90%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;   
}


.content{
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 83.3%;
    margin-left: 24px;
}

#FooterRotate{
    transform: rotate(2deg);
   /* top: 1500px;
    left: -10px; */
    height: 100px;
    width:  120%;
    background-color: #C70039;
    /*position: absolute;*/
/*    clear: both;*/
}

footer{
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #C70039;
    /*top: 1550px;
    left: -10px;*/
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 110%;
    overflow: hidden;
   /* position: absolute;*/

}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
  <h4> Welcome!</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="FooterRotate"></div>
  <footer>
       <div class="social"></div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In html static elements place after each other and has not relation to `fixed` or `absolute` position elements. If you want your main div has specific distance (for example 100px) from top, It is not a good idea to set it position absolute. It's better to manage previous elements:

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
   put here all headers element before main div
</div>
<div id="main"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

But if you do not want the way i suggested, you can do this:

```
body{min-height: 100vh;}
footer{position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```